# 403 error when scraping a URL that works on Firefox without cookies nor javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, cookies, user-agent

I have a URL that works on Firefox set to block all cookies and with JavaScript turned off, and yet when I scrape it on Python with `urllib`, I get `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. I use the same user-agent as Firefox, and here is my code:

```py
import urllib
import urllib.request

USER_AGENT_KEY = "User-Agent"
USER_AGENT_VALUE = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0'

def get_page(url)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    req.add_header(USER_AGENT_KEY, USER_AGENT_VALUE)

    # Empty SSL context, only for public websites, don't use this for banks or anything with a sign-in!
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, context = ssl.SSLContext(), timeout = TIMEOUT)

    data = response.read()
    html = data.decode('utf-8') 

    return html  # Returns "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"
```

I don't know what mechanisms a site has to detect a user other than JavaScript, cookies, or user-agent. If relevant, one URL is `https://www.idealista.pt/comprar-casas/alcobaca/alcobaca-e-vestiaria/com-preco-max_260000,apenas-apartamentos,duplex/`.

How can this site detect the scraper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web scraping with urllib / requests is unreliable. Even if you are able to load the page without being detected, some websites use JavaScript to load the data afterwards. A good way to get around this is by using [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/). Both of these tools allow you to simulate a web browser and interact with the page as if you were a real user.

Answer (score 1):

The provided URL is a dynamic website that seems to use React or another similar JS framework. This site won't work wihtout javascript. When you download the page with `curl`, you can see that you will have to enable javascript.
This means, you will not get any useful information by just downloading the html page.

The reason why you get 403 is that the page has a script embedded from https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/ which returns 403. I cannot say what this script is about, but it seems like it is some kind of geoblocking api which blocks your request due to some missing information.

Comment: Thanks! Have you any idea why that URL displays well on a Firefox browser without JavaScript and with cookies disabled and not with CURL or `requests`?

Comment: It should not work either if js is disabled in Firefox. I don't have much experience in this field so I can only make assumptions. I can think of the following: a) The website is usually rendered using SSR (server side rendering, a react feature wehre the initial rendering to html is done on the server). b) The webserver can see from the http request who issued the request (e.g. which browser) and has a scraping protection built in which blocks SSR from happening

Comment: Btw, you can use requests in python to fetch the page. It will also give you 403, but you can still access the downloaded html content which is identical to the data received with curl (=empty page with "please enable javascript..." message"). For anything else, I think you will have to stick to the answer from @linuxsushi